# C++ macro declared in a class definition?

Tags: c++, macros

I've spent the past couple of days learning C++, but I just came across something that I hadn't seen in the books nor after doing some research on Google.

As far as I know, a macro is a statement or "variable" name that is preceded by `#define` hat allows certain values or functions to be specified later and inserted where desired automatically.

However, I've come across a function that is declared inside a clas and not preceded by `#define` and it is called a "macro". The function is from MFC and is called `DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP`.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08ea0k43.aspx

Can someone explain what this type of macro is; what is it called (so I could further research it) and what does it mean?

Comment: Macros aren't scoped, or even aware of the programming language. They're processed *before* the compiler proper sees your code.

Comment: The macro is defined somewhere else, it's some microsoft specific thing, there is nothing special about it

Answer (score 2):

DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP is just a #define that is defined in the MFC (Afx.h?) set of includes. there is nothing special about compared to any other #define.

This is an old book : [MFC Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201407213) but it's a classic if you want to learn what all those things in the MFC actually do and how they work.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this](http://techleaves.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/be-careful-with-declare_message_map/) interesting:-

> If you decide to clean up and re- arrange your code, better be careful
>   about the DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP() macro that will be present in an MFC
>   derived class header file. **This macro contains a “protected” storage
>   class declaration. So everything that comes under this macro will be
>   protected unless there is any other storage class specified after
>   that. Normal error that occur during compilation will be cannot access
>   the private variable.** But you cannot easily figure out what went wrong
>   you can see only a macro call and a public storage class above.
>
> ```
> #ifdef _AFXDLL
> #define DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP() \
> private: \
>     static const AFX_MSGMAP_ENTRY _messageEntries[]; \
> protected: \
>     static AFX_DATA const AFX_MSGMAP messageMap; \
>     static const AFX_MSGMAP* PASCAL _GetBaseMessageMap(); \
>     virtual const AFX_MSGMAP* GetMessageMap() const; \
>
> #else
> #define DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP() \
> private: \
>     static const AFX_MSGMAP_ENTRY _messageEntries[]; \
> protected: \
>     static AFX_DATA const AFX_MSGMAP messageMap; \
>     virtual const AFX_MSGMAP* GetMessageMap() const; \
>
> #endif
> ```
>
> The solution is to leave it inside a protected storage class. i.e,
>   declare a protected storage class just above it and declare the
>   functions and variables that require to be protected, below it. Let
>   the public functions and variables be above the protected section with
>   proper declaration of the storage class.